# How to build unhashed files in a 'dist/' folder with ParcelJS (v2)

Tags: javascript, sass, bundler, parceljs

I'm trying to bundle some scss and js files into a `dist/main.css` and a `dist/main.js` file using Parcel (v2). I don't want any hashes within the file names (just `main.css` but not `main.182e5d44.css` and `main.js` instead of `main.3dcf9355.js`).

If I use a simple html file as an entry

`parcel build --no-content-hash main.html`

Parcel returns all files inside the `dist/` directory but uses hashes within the file names.

```
dist/main.html            219 B    748ms
dist/main.9844a242.css     89 B    853ms
dist/main.b59b001f.js      61 B    599ms
```

If I use the scss and the js file as entry points

`parcel build --no-content-hash assets/scss/main.scss assets/js/main.js`

it doesn't creates hashes of course but puts the files into subdirectories

```
dist/scss/main.css    62 B    890ms
dist/js/main.js       34 B    575ms.
```

What's the build command to achieve my desired output:

```
dist/main.css
dist/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this can be solved incredibly easily - just do not put your entry files into subdirectories

`parcel build src/index.scss src/index.js --no-content-hash --out-dir ../public/build`

There you go:

```
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ parcel build src/index.scss src/index.js --no-content-hash --out-dir ../public/build
✨  Built in 241ms.

../public/build/index.js         1.15 KB    9ms
../public/build/index.js.map       216 B    0ms
../public/build/index.css.map      190 B    4ms
../public/build/index.css           56 B    6ms
Done in 0.69s.
```

Nothing ugly about having your entry files in one point, from there just link the files in subdirectories.